# Building a C program in parallel

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, parallel-builds

I have a medium-size project which consists of many `*.c` unit files.

In a "normal" compilation exercise, the program is built from its `*.o` object files, which are passed as pre-requisite of the main program in the `Makefile` recipe. This works well for parallel builds : with `make -j`, all these object files are compiled in parallel, then linked together at the end. It makes the whole build experience a lot faster.

However, in other cases, the list of prerequisites is passed as a list of `*.c` unit files, **not** `*.o` object files. The original intention is to *not build* these object files, as they could pollute the cache.
Now, this could probably be done differently, but for this specific project, the `Makefile` is an immutable object, so it can't be updated, and we have to live with it.

In this case, using `make -j` is *not effective*, as `gcc` will effectively receive the full list of units directly on a single command line. Which means, `make` is no longer able to organize parallelism.

The only opportunity I've got left is to pass flags and parameters to `make`. I was trying to find one which would make `gcc` compile a list of units in parallel, internally. I couldn't find any. Searching around on Internet, I found conjectures stating that "since `make` can do parallel build, `gcc` doesn't need to replicate this functionality". But no solution.

So the question is : how to deal with it ?

Assuming a compilation line like `gcc *.c -o final_exe`, which can be altered through standard flags (`CC`, `CFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS`), is there any option available to make it build these units in parallel ?

Comment: "_for this specific project, the `Makefile` is an immutable object_" - Fork the project and create a proper makefile instead of trying to build something on a broken foundation.

Comment: You could maybe try writing a wrapper builder to name as `CC` which will split the work into `gcc -c` commands and a link step. But really, fixing the Makefile or moving to a different build system entirely is the better way.

Comment: It would be *relatively* easy for gcc to allow a `-j` flag. But this is not Microsoft. The Unix-filosophy is: One program solves one problem. There is no Email-functionality in GCC, either.

Comment: The short answer to your question is, no, there is no way to do that.  If you can't change the makefile then you'll have to live without parallel builds.